# Evaluating a limit involving a $\sup$, assuming uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I would like to show that if $f_n, g : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ are such that $f_n \to g$ uniformly when $n \to \infty$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $a,b \in X$ are such that $[a,b] \subset X$, then
$$
\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f_n(a)| \to \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |g(x)-g(a)| 
$$
pointwise when $n \to \infty$.

**My try** : We have that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f_n(a)-g(x)+g(a)| &\leq \sup_{x \in [a,b]} (|f_n(x)-g(x)| + |f_n(a)-g(a)|) \\
&=|f_n(a)-g(a)| + \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-g(x)| \\
&\to 0 \quad (n \to \infty).
\end{align*}
Then I thought I would like to estimate
$$
\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f_n(a)| - \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |g(x)-g(a)| 
$$
but unfortunately I don't think the following is true :
$$
\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f_n(a)-g(x)+g(a)| \leq \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f_n(a)| - \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |g(x)-g(a)|
$$
(then I would have liked to multiply by $-1$ to reverse the inequality)...

Comment: Hint1: $||a|-|b|| \le |a-b|$.

Comment: Hint2: Don't take the supremum until the very end.

Comment: I still don't get it. Ultimately, what do you want to estimate ? How do you combine $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f_n(a)|$ with $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |g(x)-g(a)|$ ? I don't see how proving that $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} ||f_n(x)-f_n(a)|-|g(x)-g(a)|| \to 0$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sufficiently large $n$, you have

$||f_n(x) - f_n(a)| - |g(x) - g(a)|| \le \epsilon$.

Opening up the outer most absolute value (or triangle inequality) gives you

$|f_n(x) - f_n(a)| \le \epsilon +|g(x) - g(a)|$

And

$|g(x) - g(a)| \le \epsilon +|f_n(x) - f(a)|$

You should be able to take it from here, but let me know if you need further hints.

Comment: All right. If I understand properly, for every $x \in X$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$, you can find a rank $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|f_n(x)-f_n(a)| \leq \epsilon + |g(x)-g(a)|$ and $|g(x)-g(a)| \leq \epsilon + |f_n(x)-f(a)|$. Since these inequalities are true for every $x \in X$, we may take the supremum in each case. Isolating $\epsilon$ on the RHS of both inequalities, we infer that $|\sup |f_n(x)-f_n(a)|-\sup |g(x)-g(a)|| \leq \epsilon$, which is equivalent to $\sup |f_n(x)-f_n(a)| \to \sup |g(x)-g(a)|$ when $n \to \infty$. Is this correct ?

Comment: You shouldn't start with "for every $x$." The $\epsilon$ and $N$ are independent of $x$, which is what allows you to take the supremum without changing the $\epsilon$. "For every $\epsilon$, there exists an $N$, so that for all $x$..." is the correct order.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much then ! I find your idea of using the reverse triangle inequality and considering an $\epsilon$ in order to separate the two $\sup$ and recombine them very clever, even though this must be a standard procedure.